# 401 when pushing to DAGsHub

Tags: git

I signed up to DAGsHub using my Github user, and I'm getting code 401 when trying to git push to my DAGsHub repo.

```
Total 8 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give more context of the problem, what exactly you did leading to the error you describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to set a password for DAGsHub.

Look carefully at the output you get from the git push.

If you have no configured password, then the output instructs you to visit your user settings menu to choose a password, which you will need to use when git pushing to DAGsHub.

Alternatively, you can create and use an access token.

BTW, DAGsHub has a support Discord channel: https://discord.com/channels/698874030052212737/698874030572437526

Comment: here is the url for you to set the password before you can push commit to DAGsHUB.
https://dagshub.com/user/settings/password